# How to handle 'Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')'

Tags: python-3.x

```
print (pd.isnull(X).sum())
#Imputer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(X)
imputed_data=imputer.transform(X)
```

When i run this code i have the following " **ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').** "

I checked for the nan value also but there is no nan value issue.

Comment: So...does your input data contain any positive or negative infinities?

Comment: there is also no positive or negative infinities.